# Pass pointer by reference

Tags: c++, pointers, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

In attempting [this HackerRank tutorial](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/c-tutorial-pointer/problem?h_r=internal-search) (in which you need to set a to a+b and b to |a-b|) I first attempted to modify the pointers to point to the new values:

```
void update(int *a,int *b) {
    // Complete this function
    int sum = *a + *b;
    int diff = *a - *b;
    if (diff < 0) diff = -diff;
    a = &sum; //these do not work, because a and b are passed by value
    b = &diff;
}
```

This doesn't work--back in main, a and b point to their original values--because (or so I understand) the pointers a and b are passed into update() by value. No problem, I thought, I'll just change the function signature to pass the pointers by reference:

```
void update(int *&a,int *&b) {
```

Sadly, this doesn't work either, but I'm at a loss for why. Can someone explain why these pointers, which appear to be passed by reference, don't get updated outside of the function's scope?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assigning addresses of local variables (`sum, diff` which go out of scope once the function exits) to `a` and `b`. It is undefined behaviour to access those addresses in `main`.
You can assign their values instead.

```
*a = sum; 
*b = diff;
```

Comment: So since it's UB, whatever compiler HackerRank uses sets the variables back to their previous values? I didn't expect that.

Comment: We cannot reliably predict what happens with undefined behavior. Anything is possible.  "there are no restrictions on the behavior of the program"

Comment: True. I just didn't expect the compiler to hold onto the old values.

Comment: @molbdnilo: using the addresses of local variables that have gone out of scope after a function exits and dereferencing them in main is not undefined behavior?

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you're already *emulating* pass by reference for integer variables, by passing them as pointers.

I suspect what you're really supposed to do is

```
*a = sum;
*b = diff;
```

Then when calling the function use the address-of operator `&` to pass pointers to normal `int` variables:

```
int sum, diff;
update(&sum, &diff);
```

---

If you go with passing references to pointers and do e.g.

```
a = &sum;
```

then you will make `a` point to a local variable. A local variable which will (in a way) cease to exist once the function returns. That means the pointer will be invalid, and dereferencing it will lead to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

And unless you need to keep compatibility with C, then in C++ use only actual references instead of emulating through pointers:

```
void update(int& a,int& b) {
    ...
    a = sum;
    b = diff;
}
```

and call it like

```
int sum, diff;
update(sum, diff);
```

Comment: I know that's what I'm supposed to do. I'm trying to gain a better understanding of reference semantics by learning why the method in the question doesn't work.